# Android Data Binding and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am converting my Android application from Java to Kotlin. It is working fine, except when I try to convert a file that is using Android Data Binding Library.
In that case, Android Studio complains at compile time about unresolved reference:

```
Error:(10, 44) Unresolved reference: AdapterHistoriesListBinding
```

Where `AdapterHistoriesListBinding` is the name of a file that should be generated by the Data Binding Library. It was working correctly in Java, so I guess it is an issue with Kotlin.

I am using Android Studio 2.0.0-beta6, Android Gradle Plugin 2.0.0-beta6 and Kotlin 1.0.
Is there something to do to make the Data Binding Library work with Kotlin?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Few steps to setup databinding in your Kotlin project.

1. Tell `kapt` to use databinding compiler in module dependencies:

   ```
   dependencies {
     kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.0.0-beta6'
   }
   ```
2. As Shintaro Katafuchi mentioned, you should tell `kapt` to generate stubs.

   ```
   kapt {
     generateStubs = true
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding following setting in your build.gradle?

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: I just tried adding that in my module's `build.gradle` (outside the `android` block), cleaned my project, but the result is the same.